# Data Sync SQL Server 2008 R2 to Azure Error

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I am trying to data sync my SQL Server 2008 R2 to Azure database but I am getting an error:

> Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncException was unhandled
>   Message=Failed to execute the command 'BulkInsertCommand' for table
>   'SleepBrightness'; the transaction was rolled back. Ensure that the
>   command syntax is correct.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540345/bulkinsertcommand-failed-in-sync-framework-2-1

Answer (score 0):

- Is it the first time you sync?
- Does the Azure database is already provisioned?
- Are you able to give use more detail about what is the difference
  from SQL server that the Azure Data Sync is trying to insert?