# Sync Framework: Failed to execute the command 'BulkInsertCommand'

Tags: .net, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using sync Framework 2.1 to synchronize two SQL Server Databases,
Sometimes i get the following exception:

Failed to execute the command 'BulkInsertCommand' on table ....

when trying to sincronize some regists present in a table of a local DB, 
and i cant figure out where the problem is..

I've read the related question but any of them solves my problem,

Does anyone had this exception before and know some possible reason why this happens, and how to solve it ?

Comment: Did you take a look at this post [BulkInsertCommand failed in Sync Framework 2.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540345/bulkinsertcommand-failed-in-sync-framework-2-1)?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't help me

Comment: run Sync Fx Tracing so you have more detailed information on the exception.

Comment: I've been debug the code, but cant find anything relevant.
Do you know some particular structure where i can find more information about the exception, for trace it ?

Answer (score 0):

For other peeps out there with the same dilemma - I have had this exception when I try to sync data that's over 1000 characters long.

I found the issue is caused by the User Defined Table used by the Bulk-stored procedures of the Sync framework. These User Defined Tables were created as part of provisioning a database for Sync and were created only with 1000 characters or `nvarchar(1000)` even if my table's schema is `nvarchar(2000)`.

I haven't found a way to configure this User Defined tables during provisioning. I do have a work around for my case although not very sustainable - [Failed to execute the command 'BulkInsertCommand' for table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645298/failed-to-execute-the-command-bulkinsertcommand-for-table)